# What would the National Debt's minimum payment warning notice read?

Tags: united-states, debt

The [CARD Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_CARD_Act_of_2009) modified what credit cards [need to disclose to you](http://www.federalreserve.gov/consumerinfo/wyntk_creditcardrules.htm) on your monthly statements. One requirement was a Minimum Payment warning:

> **Minimum Payment Warning:** If you make only the minimum payment each period, you will pay more in interest and it will take you longer to pay off your balance. For example:

[image: Minimum Payment Warning]

If we apply these rules to the current national debt, using this following assumptions:

- The minimum payment is [interest](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/reports/ir/ir_expense.htm) + **1%-2%**.
- Calculate for Public Debt held, and Intergovernmental Transfers. ([separately , together, or both](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/NP/BPDLogin?application=np))
- The interest rate is constant and at the [last known rate](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/rates/pd/avg/2012/2012_12.htm).

*Fill in the boxes*

(note: The first box contains the minimum payment and 3-year payoff amounts. The middle box contains the total years to pay off the debt paying only the minimum payment, and 3-years. The last box is the total cost of the debt after paying it off and the 3-year difference savings.)

Answer (score 7):

I finally found an [Amortization Schedule Calculator](http://www.pine-grove.com/online-calculators/national-debt-calculator.htm) that will accept figures as large as the U.S. National debt. I used the following figures (let me know if I made an error):

- National Debt, including Intergovernmental Holdings, $16,432,646,968,419
- The current Annual Interest Rate, 2.5230%
- Minimum Payment of Interest + 2% (payback 50 years), $48,227,027,367

Not that I think it is possible to pay off the debt in 3 years, as it would require payments of $5.6 trillion per year, but I have included those numbers. The calculator is quite flexible, for example you can enter the number of total U.S. adults. And assuming everyone pays there fair share and stomach the $206 or $2022 monthly payments, each person is obligated to pay $123,320 versus $72,789 (3-year savings = $50,531).

> Box 1 is $48,227,027,367 and $474,434,596,403
>
> Box 2 is 50 years and 3 years.
>
> Box 3 is $28,936,216,420,037 and $17,079,645,470,512 (Savings = $11.86 trillion)